# Azure AD B2C -> OAuth2 -> Azure Function App Token Exchange

Tags: azure, authentication, active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c

I'm fairly new to authentication, token exchanges and Azure AD B2C.

I've built an Azure AD B2C tenant in my portal and set the Redirect URI to be localhost (an Azure Function I'm running locally on Visual Studio). I know that after the browser takes you to the redirect URI it passes the authorization_code back through the URI, I'm able to save that code as a variable in my function but I'm afraid I'm lost on what to do after that. 
VS

```
 [FunctionName("Login")]
        public static string Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {

            string name = req.Query["code"];
            return name;
        }
```

I know I have to make a POST request to the /token endpoint but when I pass in the authorization_code I get this response in postman

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: a79790d9-5ab8-488e-bd5a-0e1feecd1d00\r\nCorrelation ID: 6f065d48-61d3-4193-99bf-e14f3a6951aa\r\nTimestamp: 2020-01-23 20:45:33Z",
    "error_codes": [
        900144
    ],
    "timestamp": "2020-01-23 20:45:33Z",
    "trace_id": "a79790d9-5ab8-488e-bd5a-0e1feecd1d00",
    "correlation_id": "6f065d48-61d3-4193-99bf-e14f3a6951aa",
    "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=900144"
}
```

From my function how do I pass these parameters into the body to the /token endpoint?
Any help would be appreciated. Best.

Comment: what exactly you're trying to achieve? Protect the azure function with azure ad b2c? authenticate the azure function and call external resources?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The work flow for the app would be something like new_user signsInUp through Azure AD B2C, ADB2C generates a jwt token and passes it to the azure function

Comment: ok, but what azure function will do with this token?

Comment: If you need an id_token, why don't you use the implicit flow and avoid the authorization code step? Right after the signin you'll receive an id_token.

Comment: @FuMe I've turned implicit flow on and am now seeing the id_token in the URI, how do I pass that into the azure function? I've tried using [FromBody] and HttpRequest req like above, but I'm having trouble capturing the token from the sign-in

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio the azure function will decode this token and get access the claims like oid, name and region

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand your scenario. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @FuMe the user signs up and enters their name and other details into a form from ADB2C (this comes out of the box when you set it up), it passes that information to the Redirect URI as a JWT token. I'm trying to get that JWT token passed into the parameters of my Function app (the endpoint of the Redirect URI) so i can decode it and collect the values entered during sign-up

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-webapi?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: So, you don't want to use the token to "authenticate" the Azure Function, you just want to read the token FROM the Azure Function.
Can you tell me which response_mode are you using in the initial request to B2C? Because the id_token could be in the Fragment, in the Body or in the queryString, it all depends on the response_mode parameter you used against B2C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error indicates you are using the AAD token endpoint and not the AAD B2C token endpoint.

The correct endpoints are here for AAD B2C.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc#send-authentication-requests